# Copying a table with its structure, indexes, and associated triggers?

Tags: mysql, trigger, partitioning, table, copy

I have studied this post on Stack Overflow: [Fastest way to copy a table in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943400/fastest-way-to-copy-a-table-in-mysql).

But no answer is copying everything like the table's structure, data, indexes as well as associated triggers.

- Is it possible in MySQL? If yes, how can we do this?
- Is it also possible to copy triggers from one table to another?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE a LIKE b;INSERT INTO a SELECT * FROM b`

Comment: No, it will not work. I have already tried both commands.

Comment: Tested on my machine,maybe you`re not using mysql.

Comment: I am using MysQL-5.1.53 community edition.